# need help in javascript understanding a line

Tags: javascript

```
var stooge = {
    "first-name": "Jerome",
        "last-name": "Howard"
};
var properties = [
    'first-name',
    'middle-name',
    'last-name',
    'profession'];
for (i = 0; i < properties.length; i++) {
    console.log(properties[i] + ': ' + stooge[properties[i]]);
}
```

I don't understand `stooge[properties[i]]`. Why are we using bracket before properties?
Can someone explain when to use brackets?

Comment: It is a way of accessing the properties of an object in javascript called Bracket notation.. Check this https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Member_Operators#Bracket_notation

Comment: `.` and `[]` are interchangeable, meaning `stooge.name` is the same as `stooge["name"]`. The thing is sometimes the property you want is not a valid JavaScript identifier (such as `first-name`) or is a variable (such as `properties[i]`). That's when your only choice is using the `[]` notation.

Comment: In addition to what PSL stated, the same notation is used to access arrays, as well as objects.

Comment: The same notation is used for Arrays because Arrays are Objects too. It's performing the same task in both cases.

Answer (score 1):

> I dont understand stooge[properties[i]].

It means more or less literally what it says.

If `i` is 0, then `properties[i]` is `properties[0]`, which is set to  'first-name'.

Therefore, `stooge[properties[i]]` is `stooge[properties[0]]` is `stooge['first-name']` is "Jerome".

**EDIT**

As someone pointed out, you cannot use dot-notation here. The name of the property is `first-name`. If you typed `stooge.first-name`, the parser would interpret that as `stooge.first - name`. undefined minus undefined is... NaN!

Comment: You should mention what you commented on my answer.  The question is why use brackets.  Your explanation of why dot notation won't work would be useful and relevant.

Answer (score 0):

This is just a way to access properties dynamically from an object. In this cause since there is an array of strings, it lets you get the value from the object. Since you can't do something like obj.'some-string'

This might help [JavaScript property access: dot notation vs. brackets?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4968406/javascript-property-access-dot-notation-vs-brackets)

Answer (score -1):

Object properties can be accessed with a `.`. or with `[]`.

But dot notation won't work here.

because if you switch `stooge[properties[i]]` to `stooge.properties[i]` it would return undefined, because the `stooge` object doesn't have a member named `properties`.

Comment: Not in this case.  The name of the property is `first-name`.  If you typed `stooge.first-name`, the parser would interpret that as `stooge.first - name`.  undefined minus undefined is... NaN!